# Csh to ignore case when referring filenames

Tags: command-line-interface

In csh, is there any way to ignore case in command prompt? I hope doing cp/mv/vi/etc... can just type lowercase filenames and still be able to use <kbd>tab</kbd> to auto-complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one out

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288344/cshell-tab-completion-case-insensitive

i usually don't use csh, mostly bash in which things like this are much easier.